# Create Checkbox Group from Slice

Tags: go

I'm starting out with Go and therefore this may be a simple answer but I can't find it on the net so far.

I have the following structs:

```
type Answer struct {
    AnswerId   int
    AnswerText string
    Selected   bool
}

type Answers struct {
    answers []Answer
}

type Question struct {
    QuestionId int
    Answers
    QuestionText string
}
```

This is a simple look of the domain model that backs a web app for a questionnaire.

```
func loadPage() (*Question, error) {
    return &Question{
        QuestionId:   321,
        QuestionText: "What's the answer?",
        Answers: Answers{
            answers: []Answer{
                Answer{
                    AnswerId:   1,
                    AnswerText: "Answer number 1",
                    Selected:   false,
                },
                Answer{
                    AnswerId:   2,
                    AnswerText: "Answer number 2",
                    Selected:   false,
                },
            },
        },
    }, nil
}
```

Here you can see that I've stubbed out a Question with a few answers. This has been stubbed just so I can send something to the view.

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p, _ := loadPage()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, for _,element := range p.Answers.answers {
      //Do something with each element in answers
    })
}
```

This is where I'm stuck; my `viewHandler`. What is the syntax that will allow me to create a checkbox group based upon the contents of my `answers` slice? Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: Use Go's [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package: don't print unescaped text to the response. You can call `range` in the template to populate a HTML checkbox with the current `.AnswerID` as the name, `.AnswerText` as the label and `.Selected` as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is what you can do to improve the code

```
Type Answers []Answer

type Question struct {
    QuestionId int
    // Question is not an "Answers" but has "Answers"
    Answers Answers
    QuestionText string
}
```

Instead of using embedded type to represent "IS-A" relationship, having an attribute of type Answers should be more appropriate and to avoid complex struct definition.

Now here is what your `viewHandler` might look like:

```
func ViewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // This should be loaded from another template file
    const tpl = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="demo" method="POST">
            <!-- Once the pagedata struct exists in the context,
             we can query its field value with dot notation -->
            <h3>{{.QuestionText}}</h3>
            {{range .Answers}}
                <input type="radio" name="" {{if .Selected}}checked{{end}}
                >{{.AnswerText}}<br>
            {{end}}
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
    `

    t, _ := template.New("questionaire").Parse(tpl)

    pagedata, _ := loadPage()

    // Pass in the data struct
    _ = t.Execute(w, pagedata)
}
```

You just have to parse the template, then with `Execute` pass the data struct you want its data available in the context of the response.

See the full code here https://play.golang.org/p/6PbX6YsLNt

Comment: Nice. Didn't answer my question but certainly improved by code. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Stu1986C Thought I couldn't type the code in the comment. Will check back on the question if it hasn't been answered.

Comment: Thanks @pie-o-pah I'll take a look tonight to see how it works and let you know.

Comment: I took my time getting to trying this out but it worked a treat. Thanks @pie-o-pah!